# Initialization conversion from C# to Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert the c# code below to VB. The code goes to a web page, and reads a series of text records. The content of the web response is posted below the code. This piece of code is supposed to read the query results.

```
//Post request example version 2.0
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
//Using Javascript Serializer
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
  var jS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var newJson = jS.Serialize(new SeriesPost()
  {
      seriesid = (new List() { "CUUR0000SA0" }).ToArray(),
      startyear = "",
      endyear = "",
      catalog = true,
      calculations = true,
      annualaverage = true,
      registrationKey = "EnterRegistrationKeyHere"
  });
  //View the JSON output
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newJson);
  streamWriter.Write(newJson);
  streamWriter.Flush();
  streamWriter.Close();
}
```

The results for the series ID should look like:

```
      "series": [
        {
          "seriesID": "LAUCN040010000000005",
          "data": [
            {
              "year": "2013",
              "period": "M11",
              "periodName": "November",
              "value": "16393",
              "footnotes": [
                {
                  "code": "P",
                  "text": "Preliminary."
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "year": "2013",
              "period": "M10",
              "periodName": "October",
              "value": "16536",
              "footnotes": [
                {
                 ...
                 }
              ]
            }
          ]
```

So far, I've got the code below.

```
        Dim streamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
        streamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        Dim jS As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim SeriesPost() As Array
        SeriesPost = New SeriesPost() With {.seriesid = (New List() {"CUUR0000SA0"}).ToArray(),
                .startyear = "",
                .endyear = "",
                .catalog = True,
                .calculations = True,
                .annualaverage = True,
                .registrationKey = "EnterRegistrationKeyHere"
}
        Dim newJson As String
        newJson = jS.Serialize(loSeriesPost)

        '  //View the JSON output
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newJson)
        streamWriter.Write(newJson)
        streamWriter.Flush()
        streamWriter.Close()
```

I can't figure out how to initialize SeriesPost and how to convert this initialization to VB.

Please advise.

Thank you.
Alexander

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to compile the C# to an assembly and then get a good decompiler to decompile the intermediate language (IL) code in the assembly back to VB.  Unfortunately, the freebie JetBrains DotPeek only decompiles to C# (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/)

Comment: Your new `SeriesPost` looks fine.  Initializing `SeriesPost` as an array (and an untyped one at that) is surprising, especially since there isn't an array in the C# (in C# you would expect square brackets `[` and `]` to indicate an array).  What's going wrong with your VB?

Comment: This isn't a problem, exactly, since it's in the original C#, but it's surprising to create a new `List` (apparently untyped... is it even from the framework?) and then immediately turn it into an array.  I would normally expect to just create a new array directly, the syntax would be almost the same and you would avoid the inefficiency of creating and throwing away the list.

Comment: @Craig: C# has a line "seriesid = (new List() { "CUUR0000SA0" }).ToArray(),", so some array is expected.

Comment: I'm suggesting that it would be more logical to use `seriesid = new[] { "CUUR000SA0" };` (which will create an array directly) rather than running it through a list.  As I said, it's not a *problem* really, it's just surprising.

Comment: @Craig: I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim httpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/"), HttpWebRequest)
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"

    Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        Dim jS = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim newJson = jS.Serialize(New SeriesPost() With {
            .seriesid = (New List() From {
                "CUUR0000SA0"
            }).ToArray(),
            .startyear = "",
            .endyear = "",
            .catalog = True,
            .calculations = True,
            .annualaverage = True,
            .registrationKey = "EnterRegistrationKeyHere"
        })
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newJson)
        streamWriter.Write(newJson)
        streamWriter.Flush()
        streamWriter.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with what you changed and why?

Comment: You should also add "Option Infer On". Otherwise the variables are 'Object' and the code won't compile.

Comment: Thank you duerzd696. Would you please clarify how to define type of class SeriesPost?

Comment: @Craig: the program is written in VB, that's why the conversion is requied.

Comment: I defined a class SeriesPost As                                                                                     Public Class SeriesPost
  Public seriesid As Array
  Public startyear As String
  Public endyear As String
  Public catalog As Boolean
  Public calculations As Boolean
  Public annualaverage As Boolean
  Public registrationKey As String
 End Class. Now the program compiles OK. However, only the header is printed for newJson, with no underlying data.

Comment: @Alexander I know that conversion is required.  You had already provided some not-working VB code, I was asking duerzd696 to give some details on how and why they modified your code so that it might be more generally useful than just fixing your problem.